# problem in a basic initial value problem $ \begin{cases} \ y'=t(y-1)^2\\ \ y(0)=0\\ \end {cases} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, initial-value-problems

> part one:$
> \begin{cases}
> \ y'=t(y-1)^2\\
> \ y(0)=0\\
> \end {cases}
> $
>
> $y(2)=?$
>
> part two is similar but:
> $
> \begin{cases}
> \ y'=t(y-1)^2\\
> \ y(0)=1\\
> \end {cases}
> $
>
> also need to find $y(2)$

---

I solved it using the separable equation method

$\frac{dy}{dt}=t(y-1)^2$ $\iff$ $\int \frac{dy}{(y-1)^2}=\int tdt$ $\iff$ $-\frac{1}{y-1}=\frac{t^2}{2}+C$ now plugging in our initial value $\frac{2}{0-1}=0+C$ we get $C=-2$

so out function is $\frac{2}{y-1}=-t^2-2$ now to find $y(t=2)$ we have $\frac{2}{y-1}=-4-2$ $\iff$ $\frac{2}{-6}=y-1$ and finally $y=\frac{2}{3}$

for part two it is obviously the same integral so we have
$-\frac{1}{y-1}=\frac{t^2}{2}+C$

but I cannot plug in $y(0)=1$ because then I get $\frac{1}{1-1}=\frac{1}{0}$

what am I missing?

Thanks for any help and tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done correctly for the first IVP.

The second IVP has no non constant solution.

---

Edit: Thanks to @conan for pointing out my fatal mistake.In the first place to solve the integration you have divided by $y-1$ which is valid only for $y(t) \neq 1$.

But $y(t) =1 $ solves the ode as well as satisfy the initial condition.

Hence $y(t) =1$ is the solution of the IVP.

But it doesn't have any non constant solution!

Comment: thank you ,so in the second part , can $y(2)=1$ be considered a solution ?

Comment: y(t) = 1 is a solution that satisfies the second IVP

Comment: @conan Sorry for the question but I am now confused , it does satisfy or not?

Comment: When you divide by $(y-1)^{2}$ initially to solve it. You assume $y \neq 1$. But what if $y = 1$? You can try $y(t) = 1$ to see if its a solution, and it is. That makes $y(2) = 1$ aswell.

Comment: @conan Thank you! this is what I was missing.. when dividing I missed a possible solution